# Creating XML Transform file for MS Access import

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I need help creating an XSLT transform file for following XML code.
In the end the imported data in access should have following columns:
"Message UID", "Time", "IRCPTACTION", "TRACKERID", "ORCPTS", "DELIVER", "ACCEPT", "TLS_RECEIVED", "SENDER", "SOURCE", "SUBJECT"... and so on.

I tried to create my XSLT file base on some of the examples on this site but since Im pre noob status when it comes to XML I did not get very far.

Can Someone help me build the first part of the XSLT File?

```
    <message UID="d4622233-f99ff70000003b12-f4-59b0dc8a55f9">
    <events>
        <event time="1504763018" name="IRCPTACTION">Test@test.com|deliver</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="TRACKERID">Test@test.com|iiiiiddddddd</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="ORCPTS">Test@test.com</event>
        <event time="1504763019" name="DELIVER">192.168.1.1:25|Test@test.com</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="ACCEPT">192.168.1.2:33564</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="TLS_RECEIVED">yes</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="SENDER">Me</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="SOURCE">external</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="SUBJECT">Test Message</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="MSGID">Message_ID;</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="MSG_SIZE">2</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="EHLO">MyServer</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="LOGICAL_IP">192.168.1.1</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="FIRED">Test@test.com|none</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="VERDICT">Test@test.com|none|default</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="UNTESTED">Test@test.com|has_urls|dz_document|</event>
    </events>
</message>
<message UID="d4622233-f81ff70000003b12-c8-59b0105f670f">
    <events>
                    <event time="1504763018" name="IRCPTACTION">Test@test.com|deliver</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="TRACKERID">Test@test.com|iiiiiddddddd</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="ORCPTS">Test@test.com</event>
        <event time="1504763019" name="DELIVER">192.168.1.1:25|Test@test.com</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="ACCEPT">192.168.1.2:33564</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="TLS_RECEIVED">yes</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="SENDER">Me</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="SOURCE">external</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="SUBJECT">Test Message</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="MSGID">Message_ID;</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="MSG_SIZE">2</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="EHLO">MyServer</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="LOGICAL_IP">192.168.1.1</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="FIRED">Test@test.com|none</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="VERDICT">Test@test.com|none|default</event>
        <event time="1504763018" name="UNTESTED">Test@test.com|has_urls|dz_document|</event>
    </events>
</message>
```

Comment: You can't have the final table structure you described because the `time` value for "DELIVER" is not the same as the others. (Unless, of course, you decide to throw it away. In that case you would need to decide which `time` is the "right" one when there is more than one value per message.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply re-write the `<message>` and `<event>` nodes by mapping `@name` attribute to element name and retaining text. *MESSAGE_UID* and *TIMER* run once since it is same for all children.

**XSLT** *(assumes `<messages>` is the root with no xmlns namespace)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/messages">  
        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="message"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- RE-WRITE MESSSAGE NODE -->
    <xsl:template match="message"> 
        <xsl:copy>  
            <MESSAGE_UID><xsl:value-of select="@UID"/></MESSAGE_UID>
            <TIMER><xsl:value-of select="events/event/@time"/></TIMER>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="events/event"/>
        </xsl:copy>       
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- MAP ATTRIBUTE TO NEW NODE NAMES, RETAINING EVENT TEXT -->
    <xsl:template match="events/event">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** *(flat enough to import into MS Access table)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<messages>
  <message>
    <MESSAGE_UID>d4622233-f99ff70000003b12-f4-59b0dc8a55f9</MESSAGE_UID>
    <TIMER>1504763018</TIMER>
    <IRCPTACTION>Test@test.com|deliver</IRCPTACTION>
    <TRACKERID>Test@test.com|iiiiiddddddd</TRACKERID>
    <ORCPTS>Test@test.com</ORCPTS>
    <DELIVER>192.168.1.1:25|Test@test.com</DELIVER>
    <ACCEPT>192.168.1.2:33564</ACCEPT>
    <TLS_RECEIVED>yes</TLS_RECEIVED>
    <SENDER>Me</SENDER>
    <SOURCE>external</SOURCE>
    <SUBJECT>Test Message</SUBJECT>
    <MSGID>Message_ID;</MSGID>
    <MSG_SIZE>2</MSG_SIZE>
    <EHLO>MyServer</EHLO>
    <LOGICAL_IP>192.168.1.1</LOGICAL_IP>
    <FIRED>Test@test.com|none</FIRED>
    <VERDICT>Test@test.com|none|default</VERDICT>
    <UNTESTED>Test@test.com|has_urls|dz_document|</UNTESTED>
  </message>
  <message>
    <MESSAGE_UID>d4622233-f81ff70000003b12-c8-59b0105f670f</MESSAGE_UID>
    <TIMER>1504763018</TIMER>
    <IRCPTACTION>Test@test.com|deliver</IRCPTACTION>
    <TRACKERID>Test@test.com|iiiiiddddddd</TRACKERID>
    <ORCPTS>Test@test.com</ORCPTS>
    <DELIVER>192.168.1.1:25|Test@test.com</DELIVER>
    <ACCEPT>192.168.1.2:33564</ACCEPT>
    <TLS_RECEIVED>yes</TLS_RECEIVED>
    <SENDER>Me</SENDER>
    <SOURCE>external</SOURCE>
    <SUBJECT>Test Message</SUBJECT>
    <MSGID>Message_ID;</MSGID>
    <MSG_SIZE>2</MSG_SIZE>
    <EHLO>MyServer</EHLO>
    <LOGICAL_IP>192.168.1.1</LOGICAL_IP>
    <FIRED>Test@test.com|none</FIRED>
    <VERDICT>Test@test.com|none|default</VERDICT>
    <UNTESTED>Test@test.com|has_urls|dz_document|</UNTESTED>
  </message>
</messages>
```

Comment: Awesome XML skills. Thank you. 
I will try to wrap my head around it in the weekend why it works. :-)

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Happy coding! XSLT is a bit different than other languages but once you grasp it, it can be elegant!